# Laravel 5 optional route params with required params

Tags: php, laravel

So basically I'm trying to create a simple page that handles no params, or if one param is called, then the other is required, what's the best way to do this?

So for example, I could have **example.com**

but then if I clicked a specific link on the page it'd append **example.com/{id}/{name}**

My issue is that I want to be able to do it a maximum of 3 times **example.com/{id?}/{name}/{id?}/{name}/{id?}/{name}**

Basically interpreting that if **id** is passed, then **name** is required, would this be the correct way to go about this or would there be an easier method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@method');
Route::get('/{id}/{name}', 'HomeController@method');
Route::get('/{id}/{name}/{id2}/{name2}', 'HomeController@method');
Route::get('/{id}/{name}/{id2}/{name2}/{id3}/{name3}', 'HomeController@method');
```

However, you still have to handle the **404 exception** for **NotFoundHttpException** error.

Hope it helps. Cheers!